# How to escape a double quote in nmake

Tags: visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-2013, nmake

I'm trying to pass a string literal via a `/D` flag to the compiler via an nmake script in MS Visual Studio 2013+. The basic pattern is:

```
CPPFLAGS=/DSOME_STRING_VAR="asdf"

main.exe: main.cpp
    $(CPP) $(CPPFLAGS) # ...
```

And inside main.cpp I'd like to be able to do something like:

```
const char *some_string_var = SOME_STRING_VAR;
```

So far, every variation of this I try results in something like:

```
main.cpp(271) : error C2065: 'asdf' : undeclared identifier
```

I've tried one double-quote `"`, escaping with a caret `^"`, multiple-escaping the caret `^^^"`, and doubling up the double-qoute `""`. All of these are, as far as I can tell, escape syntaxes for batch scripts, but they don't seem to work in nmake.

Is there a way to escape double quotes in nmake so that they get properly passed into the compile command?

For bonus points, are nmake command executed by a shell such at batch? I.e. do I have to worry about one or two levels of escaping here?

I'd be happy to support Visual Studio 2015+ if there were a cleaner solution enabled by the newer version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tldr: Escape the double-quotes with a *backslash*.

---

If your test file `main.cpp` is:

```
#include <iostream>
int main() {
  const char *some_string_var = SOME_STRING_VAR;
  std::cout << some_string_var << std::endl;
}
```

then the command:

```
CL /DSOME_STRING_VAR=\"asdf\" main.cpp
```

will work as desired, with the test program giving:

```
>.\main.exe
asdf
```

And if your `makefile` is the single line:

```
CPPFLAGS=/DSOME_STRING_VAR=\"asdf\"
```

then:

```
>nmake main.exe
```

will also work.

I was not able to find any reference for this. Tested on VS2013 and VS2017.